# Proof of Prop. I.27 in Euclid's Elements

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

Let´s suppose I have lines $\overleftrightarrow{EB}, \overleftrightarrow{CD}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{EF}$, as shown in the picture and , and angle $BCD$ is equal to angle $CEF$, how can I prove $\overleftrightarrow{CD}$ is parallel to $\overleftrightarrow{EF}$? I "made" one demonstration but I would like to know how you´d do it.

So, this is how I proved it.

[image]

$Demonstration:$

$Hypothesis:$ We have straight lines as show in the picture ... and angles $BCD\cong CEF$.

$Thesis:$ $\overleftrightarrow{CD}$ is parallel to $\overleftrightarrow{EF}.$

So, let´s suppose that they are *not* parallel, therefore, there is a point $P$, in which $\overleftrightarrow{CD}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{EF}$ intersect, so that I can make the triangle $CEP$.

Because it´s a triangle,  its interior angles sum to $180°$ degrees. Supposing that angle $CEF$ equals to $x$ degrees, I can say that angle $ECP$ is equal to $180 - x $, because both have to sum to $180°$. So now, supposing that triangle $CEP$ is a *real* triangle, angle $P$ has to measure $a°$ ($a$, being a positive real number and $a\neq 0$), so when I sum the angles, I get: $$ x + (180 - x) +a = 180
$$ $$ 180 + a = 180
$$ $$a=0
$$

So, I end up having a contradiction, thefore $\overleftrightarrow{CD}$ is parallel to $\overleftrightarrow{EF}$.

I could have also, as you say, proven it by contradiction, using the external angle theorem, because (I think) that would suggest, in this case angle $P=0$.

So what do you think? . I problably posted this, because I think I am being redudant, and also because it is not exactly how Euclid proves it.

@Aretino, I didn´t know how to make a comment and put a phot in it so I had to edit the comment. So I this is what I thought:

[image]

So, you first follow the steps and you get that $\angle BEC \cong \angle FEA$. And by $LAL$ you have that $\triangle BEC \cong \triangle FEA$ and $\angle EBC \cong \angle FAE \cong \angle HAI$, and I think that´s how we would get to a contradiction.

Comment: Lookup [Euclid's I.27](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI27.html): "*If a straight line falling on two straight lines makes the alternate angles equal to one another, then the straight lines are parallel to one another*".

Comment: You should give your demonstration, so that we don't waste time duplicating your effort and/or telling you things that you already know.

Comment: That is usually done by contradiction, using the external angle theorem. One doesn't need the parallel postulate.

Comment: That is Prop. 27 in Book I of Euclid's Elements, see here: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI27.html

Comment: The three angles of a triangle summing to two right angles is an equivalent of the parallel postulate.  If that is your version of the postulate or you have already proven it, your proof is fine.  You should also show that it also works if the intersection point is to the right, but it is essentially the same argument.

Comment: I don't understand your last proof, because you changed letters. Anyway, that's not what I intended in my answer: I'll edit it to explain better what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof looks fine, but you are using a result (sum of the interior angles of a triangle) which requires the parallel postulate. This theorem can be proved **without** using that postulate (and in a simpler way) by [the exterior angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_angle_theorem): in triangle $CEP$ (I'm referring to the construction shown in the question) exterior angle $\angle BCD$ must be greater than remote interior angle $\angle CEP$, but in our case those two angles are equal, so we get a contradiction.

Of course I'm referring to Euclid's Exterior Angle Theorem, not to the theorem unfortunately given the same name by some high-school books (see the Wikipedia page linked above for details).

EDIT.

As the above description is not clear enough, here's a more detailed version of the proof. We will use [Euclid's Exterior Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_angle_theorem):

> An exterior angle of a triangle is greater than either
>   of the interior angles not adjacent to it.

This is a fundamental result in [absolute geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_geometry) because its proof does not depend upon the parallel postulate. For the proof, see the Wikipedia page linked above, or [Euclid's Elements](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI16.html).

We can now proceed to prove the theorem you asked about: lines $CD$ and $EF$ make equal corresponding angles $\angle BCD$ and $\angle CEF$ with line $BC$; we must prove that $CD$ and $EF$ are parallel.

Suppose, by contradiction, that $CD$ and $EF$ are not parallel and thus meet at some point $P$. A triangle $PCE$ is then formed, but that triangle has an exterior angle ($\angle BCD$ in diagram below) which is equal to an interior angle not adjacent to it ($\angle CEF$). That is not possible by the exterior angle theorem, according to which $\angle BCD$ must be greater than $\angle CEF$.

We thus get a contradiction and $CD$ is parallel to $EF$.

[image]

It is worth noting that this theorem allows one to construct a line parallel to a given line and passing through a given point: the **existence** of such a line can then be proven in absolute geometry, as it doesn't require the parallel postulate. The latter is needed to ensure the **uniqueness** of the constructed parallel line.

Comment: Well, I have seen the post in Wikipedia, followed the steps of the demonstration, but (I might have not understood it completely) I think that it only proves that $a\lt x$.

Comment: The Wikipedia page is about the exterior angle theorem. Then you must apply it in your case, following the same steps as in your proof. The only difference is that the contradiction arises from triangle $CEP$ having an exterior angle ($\angle BCD$) equal to an interior angle ($\angle CEP$). That is not possible, because the exterior angle theorem requires $\angle BCD>\angle CEP$.

Comment: But if you are in High School and your book doesn't mention this external angle theorem, then be content of your proof, even if it is redundant.

Comment: I think I´ve got what you say. Can I make the drawing? (I ask this because I think I am being conceited).

Comment: Of course you can, sorry for the delay in replying.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the parallel postulate are you using?  Your problem clearly requires it.  The converse of what you are trying to prove is one of the common equivalents.  If your parallel postulate is that the angles of a triangle sum to $\pi$, you can imagine the lines meeting to the right and making a triangle.  You can show the angles sum to more than $\pi$.  Then do the same to the left.

Comment: That´s what I did, I tried to prove by contradiction, and we end up having a "triangle" with either its angles summing to more than $\pi$, or a triangle with an angle of $0°$ degrees.

Comment: This proof doesn't need the parallel postulate. Just use the exterior angle theorem.

Comment: @Aretino: that is one of the equivalents of the parallel postulate, so it uses whatever version OP is using.  We can be sure the parallel postulate is involved because this fails on the sphere

Comment: On the sphere it is not only the parallel postulate which is different. This theorem is valid in hyperbolic geometry and in absolute geometry.

Comment: See also here: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI27.html

Comment: How is then I can prove it WITHOUT the parallel postulate?

Comment: @Aretino:. You can't. This theorem is not true in absolute geometry because spherical geometry is absolute  plus the applicable negation of the parallel postulate so all absolute geometry theorems are true in spherical geometry. If you look at the proof carefully the parallel postulate or an equivalent is invoked.

Comment: Please read the web page I linked above, in particular in the "Guide" section, where it says: "Although this is the first proposition about parallel lines, it does not require the parallel postulate Post.5 as an assumption. "